# Cross-Site Question bans?

Tags: discussion, post-ban, site-crossover

I got question banned on Serverfault for asking some bad questions I do admit not my best work. When I tried to post a question on Stackoverflow I realized I was also Question banned. Considering I only have one question with a zero rating and a account reputation of three. I was wondering if the ban was across multiple sites? If so, do I have to raise my reputation on Serverfault or will it work with Stackoverflow as well. If it is a separate ban don't you think that's a little bit steep considering new user wont be stack exchange experts in one or to post.

**Edit:**

With what Robert Harvey said I have concluded that they are separate bans. What i find hard is I'm new to programming so I don't know very much about it. How am I supposed to answer questions if I don't understand what there're talking about, never mind what the question is. Its like this on 90% of the site and the other %10 already have better answers that I can give.

I could go read about programming but I don't understand it unless i use it in Practice. I can't use it if I don't understand it. It has created and endless loop where I understand something because I can't ask about it. I can't ask ask about it because I don't understand it.

My opinion though effective the auto ban has a crippling effect on new users that are trying to learn. I think it should be more lenient so users that are trying should not get banned after two questions. Because what's going to happen is they will just make a new account to ask questions and it will repeat.

**What Robert Harvey said:**

You've got some negatively-scored questions which are deleted (SO doesn't show deleted questions in profiles). –  Robert Harvey

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any old questions that were deleted on SO? They count as well and I'm pretty sure the question bans don't span across sites.

Comment: Hard to tell.  You logged in here under an account that's not associated to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3146886/spik330.  You've got some negatively-scored questions which are deleted (SO doesn't show deleted questions in profiles).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ok so it is a separate ban why was I not banned then or before I asked my question. Rather that wait till a bit of time passed? which bring up a another point that's a bit steep for bans.

Comment: No, question ban is per-site. On very extreme cases moderator can manually give cross network suspension, but that's really not the case here. You just asked bad questions on two sites.

Comment: @People who down vote this. I'm confused at why you would rate this question down because I asked a completely legitimate question. And The question has bin answered. Compared to the "How do I ask a good question" the question is good. So your problem is you don't agree with something I said. Rather than rating it down and saying its a bad question why don't you say what you don't agree with.